# How to use Apollo Client with AppSync?

Tags: websocket, mqtt, apollo, react-apollo, aws-appsync

AppSync uses MQTT over WebSockets for its subscription, yet Apollo uses WebSockets. Neither `Subscription` component or `subscribeForMore` in `Query` component works for me when using apollo with AppSync.

> One AppSync feature that generated a lot of buzz is its emphasis on
>   real-time data. Under the hood, AppSync’s real-time feature is powered
>   by GraphQL subscriptions. While Apollo bases its subscriptions on
>   WebSockets via subscriptions-transport-ws, subscriptions in GraphQL
>   are actually flexible enough for you to base them on another messaging
>   technology. Instead of WebSockets, AppSync’s subscriptions use MQTT as
>   the transport layer.

Is there any way to make use of AppSync while still using Apollo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, here is how it worked for me. You'll need to use `aws-appsync` SDK (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js) to use Apollo with AppSync. Didn't have to make any other change to make subscription work with AppSync.

Configure ApolloProvider and client:

```js
    // App.js
    import React from 'react';
    import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
    import { AppLoading, Asset, Font, Icon } from 'expo';
    import AWSAppSyncClient from 'aws-appsync' // <--------- use this instead of Apollo Client
    import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo' 
    import { Rehydrated } from 'aws-appsync-react' // <--------- Rehydrated is required to work with Apollo

    import config from './aws-exports'
    import { SERVER_ENDPOINT, CHAIN_ID } from 'react-native-dotenv'
    import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

    const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
      url: config.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
      region: config.aws_appsync_region,
      auth: {
        type: config.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
        apiKey: config.aws_appsync_apiKey,
        // jwtToken: async () => token, // Required when you use Cognito UserPools OR OpenID Connect. token object is obtained previously
      }
    })


    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Rehydrated>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <AppNavigator />
            </View>
          </Rehydrated>  
        </ApolloProvider>
    }
```

Here is how the subscription in a component looks like:

```js
    <Subscription subscription={gql(onCreateBlog)}>
      {({data, loading})=>{
        return <Text>New Item: {JSON.stringify(data)}</Text>
      }}
    </Subscription>
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention that the `aws-exports` file comes from the main page of AppSync from the JavaScript tabs. Down in the page, there's a button that says "Download config". That's the file you want to include.

Comment: In addition, if you're using TypeScript, check this link out: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/362 There seems to be a Typings issue from the AppSync Client (outdated typings)

Comment: @C.Lee Did you have any problems with broken websockets after network change? Should it re-connect automatically after e.g. VPN connect?

Comment: With this code, isn't it only working on development machine? How do you get it to work in production?

Comment: As per Jan 1, 2022 MTQQ is no longer available as protocol in AppSync https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/aws-appsync-real-time-data.html

Answer (score 4):

Just to add a note about the authentication as it took me a while to work this out:

If the authenticationType is "API_KEY" then you have to pass the apiKey as shown in @C.Lee's answer.

```
  auth: {
    type: config.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
    apiKey: config.aws_appsync_apiKey,
  }
```

If the authenticationType is "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS" then you need the jwkToken, and 
if you're using Amplify you can do this as

```
  auth: {
    type: config.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
    jwtToken: async () => {
      const session = await Auth.currentSession();
      return session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
    }
  }
```

But if your authenticationType is "AWS_IAM" then you need the following:

```
  auth: {
    type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM,
    credentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials()
  }
```

Comment: Hey Denis, Do you have a solution for AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS where Amplify is not being used?
I cannot find it anywhere, but cant use Amplify on this project

Comment: Sorry @JoshuaJames, I don't. We've used Amplify in our React Native app and in the web version we've used the Cognito UI provided by AWS. It's a bit basic but it does the job.