# AWS App Sync Subscriptions over MQTT is not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, subscription, aws-appsync, graphql-subscriptions, graphql-mutation

While using AWS AppSync SDK to add subscription its returning this error, but I got the result in AWS console.

```
errorType: "BadRequestException"
message: "Subscriptions over MQTT is not supported."
```

I have seen this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935653/aws-app-sync-subscriptions-not-working-because-of-mqtt-error) and tried the answers that doesn't worked for me.
Is there any way to solve this error? looking forward to the suggestions
Thank you

Comment: Hi  @Rawan did you find any solution for this?

Comment: We didn't find any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to de deprecation of MQTT

So instead of configuring
createSubscriptionHandshakeLink as createSubscriptionHandshakeLink(url, httpLink)
you must use createSubscriptionHandshakeLink({ url, region, auth }) or it will result to using MQTT

ref:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/628